# Refinando resultados pós busca (PHP -AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax, menu

Gostaria de saber como fazer um menu vertical com um form para atualização dos dados sem refresh e sem ter que apertar o submit. Apenas com click na opção que quer mudar. 
Tipo se eu fiz uma pesquisa e apareceram os resultados, e ao lado desses resultados ter um menu vertical, com as opções disponíveis.
ex:
Resultados do icarros,
Apos mudar o ano ou ano inicial ou final, localizado no menu lateral, ele muda os dados da busca sem refresh.
Como fazer aquele menu lateral? Ajuda!

Comment: Poste o que vc já tentou fazer.

Comment: Nos dê um ponto de partida.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente baixe a biblioteca jQuery no link https://jquery.com/download/ e faça a inclusão deste arquivo no head do seu site ex:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="path/seu arquivo.js"></script>
</head>
```

Crie um arquivo vazio com a extenção .js ex: busca.js para colocar o código que executará o AJAX.

HTML:

```
<select name="filter" id="filter">
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
```

Crie um método em uma classe php no caso se você estiver utilizando um framework, faça a busca e retorno os dados no formato JSON. Caso você esteja utilizando um site com o código estruturado crie um arquivo por exemplo filtro.php.

No arquivo busca.js você pode usár o evento change que é executado após o usuário selecionar o filtro ex:

```
$(function(){
    $('#filter').change(function(){
        var $filtro = $(this);
        $.ajax({
        url: 'filtro.php',
      type: 'get',
      data:{
        ano: $filtro.val()
      },
      success: function(response){
         alert(response); // retorno do php
      },
      error: function(xhr){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
     });
   });
});
```

seguindo está orientação no arquivo php, você deve capiturar a requisição para fazer a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
$filtro = $_REQUEST['ano']; ou $_GET['ano'];
```